# Why does this URL data passing work but the other does not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have two ajax requests that run from javascript in my view.

The first view instance:

```
var id = $(element).data("id");
var fullname = $(element).data("fullname");
var count = element.checked ? -1 : 1;
var rowIndex = $(element).closest("tr").index();

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Edit", "Booking")/" + id + "?fullname=" + fullname + "&type=" + count,
```

The first controller instance:

```
[HttpPost]
public int Edit(int id, string fullname, string type)
{
```

This transfers the id, fullname and type variable values from the url generated in the ajax request. Perfect!

The second view instance:

```
var type = "Table"; //this will be dynamically set later (could be type=table or type=new)
alert("[" + dateFrom + "] [" + dateTo + "]");

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Booking")/" + type + "?datefrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateto=" + dateTo,
```

The second controller instance:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(string type, string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
```

The second instance the url is generated fine (I think) so it directs to /Booking/Create/Table?datefrom= etc however the string type variable is always null, how can I grab the type variable as "Table" in this case?

I can't seem to get my head around why the first instance works, however the second instance doesn't as it looks the same to me.

Thanks

Comment: Probably due to routing rules I would guess. ID I would guess is recognised as a potential route parameter and therefore picked up from the URL path, where as type is not, unless you've modified the rules. You'd have to do it as `?type=" + type + "&datefrom=` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your route definitions.  In your route table, you have the generic entry that looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

The line that looks like `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` is what automatically maps the supplied parameters to a pretty URL.  Note the last item is named `id`.  If you send a parameter named ID in your URL, it will be converted to the pretty format such as `Home/Index/4`.  Conversly, that same URL will supply the value of `4` to the `id` parameter of your controller action.

Your second example, you are passing a parameter named type, however, you have no route that tells MVC what to do with the `type` parameter when it is part of the actual URL (eg `controller/action/type`).  As a result, MVC is not mapping the last part of your URL to the type parameter.

You can do one of two things.

1 - Create a new route that looks for a parameter named type

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyTypeRoute",                                              
    "{controller}/{action}/{type}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", type = "" }
);
```

2 - Treat the `type` parameter just like the other two when building your URL

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Booking")?type=" + type + "&datefrom=" + dateFrom + "&dateto=" + dateTo,
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! Is there any reason you keep the controller as "Home" and not "Booking" in the route map?

Comment: @Tatrick - nope, no reason.  You can totally change the controller to "Booking" in your new route!